# PL/SQL object member function - java method

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying make an oracle object wich member function calls java method. It HAS to be member function, not static function.

Java class:

```
Create or Replace Java Source Named "Hello" As
public class Hello {
  public String World() { return "Hello World!"; }
}
```

Object:

```
Create or replace type T_HelloW as object(
helloID int,
member function HelloWorld return varchar2 as
language java name 'Hello.World() return java.lang.String');
```

Table creation and data insert:

```
create table hellos of T_HelloW;
insert into hellos values(1);
```

But when I try to call it:

```
select h.HelloWorld() from hellos h;
```

I get error:

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected an IN argument at position 1 that is an instance of an Oracle type convertible to an instance of a user defined Java class got an Oracle type that could not be converted to a java class

932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

*Cause:
*Action:

I have red http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chsix.htm#BABJJFJC
Actually the only information I found about this. And I don't see what I am missing or doing wrong.

Comment: This is something I've never done before, so I cannot give you proper advice, but have your read the doc up to the end? Especially [the part about implementing SQLData](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chsix.htm#sthref460) ?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think it is not related to the problem. As it says - To make access to object attributes more natural, create a Java class that implements the SQLData interface. In this case I don't even need to access object attributes.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I am sorry, that was it. Altought I don't fully understand why I needed to implement that in this case.

Comment: @John - please re-edit your question.  remove the 'solution' section and post that as an answer.  StackOverflow is a Q&A site; as such, it values questions *with answers*.  It is perfectly legitimate to post  and accept an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution  is as Sylvain Leroux suggested. Had to implement SQLData interface:

```
Create or Replace Java Source Named "Hello" As

import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Hello implements SQLData {
  private int helloId;
  public String World() { return "Hello World!"; }
  String sql_type;

  public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
    return sql_type;
  }

  public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {
    sql_type = typeName;
    helloId = stream.readInt();
  }

  public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
    stream.writeInt(helloId);
  }
}
```

Comment: But how do I return nested objects?